# java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_height attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, height

How can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Detail_comment"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/heightrvComment">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/heightToolbar"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I can't find  what's wrong on my code. Help me.
I think I've put all `layout_height` and `layout_width` correctly.

Comment: `You must supply a layout_height attribute` - what is not clear here?

Comment: Post your `toolbar.xml` layout.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for all responses.

I forgot to write "dp" in dimen value, so android studio return that response.

Hopefully, i'll be more careful :D.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Change the `layout_height` and `layout_width` attribute to below of `android:...` declaration

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Detail_comment"android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Detail_comment">

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all namespaces at the start. `android:layout_height` uses `xmlns:android` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

properties below your `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

The concept is similar to the variable declaration. First, you need declare the properties then only you can assign them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constant height please put below code on that.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```